# iOS9 : App Transport Security inside .plist Framework

Tags: ios, ios9.3, app-transport-security

I had create a Framework that using NSURLSessionDataTask (HTTP) to send request to server, but whenever I use the Framework in Example app, it show warning like this :

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

I tried to add App Transport Security inside Framework .plist but still not working. But, It work when I add App Transport Security in .plist outside Framework.

Is there any solution for this problem ?, Thanks

Comment: The exception is granted to your app, not the specific framework. Just add it in your app's Info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

As @EmilioPelaez stated, the application controls whether ATS is active or not.  If your framework does something that violates the ATS rules, each app that uses the framework will need to add the appropriate exceptions.

There is good reason for this behavior. Take, for example, a generic network helper framework, where the URLs are provided to the framework calls by the calling application.  The framework would have no way of knowing whether it will need ATS.  Conversely, if the framework has hard-coded URLs in it that require ATS exceptions, the calling app developer should be aware of that and it shouldn't be obscured by the face that the framework developer added exceptions.  I, as a developer, would want to know I was using a framework that was inherently insecure.  If you are dealing with the latter scenario, simply put in your framework documentation the exceptions that are needed for the framework to function properly.

Also, as a best practice with ATS, **don't just disable it altogether**,  there are specific exceptions that can be used to minimize your security risk exposure by only disabling certain parts of the ATS requirements for specific domains.  Be sure you do that.  Also, understand that Apple planned to require justification for many ATS exceptions at the end of 2016, but it has been postponed at the moment.  If you add exceptions, you should be prepared that at some point, when you submit the app to the App Store, you will be asked by Apple for a reason.  It probably shouldn't be "because stack overflow told me to disable all ATS".

Answer (score 0):

The framework doesn't have control over ATS, the app does. So you have to write it down in your documentation, that the app developer needs to add ATS exceptions to his app.

That said, don't do that. Especially if you're making a framework. Take time and add HTTPS support to the server / contact the server developer to add it. Because Apple will stop supporting AllowArbitraryLoads / exceptions soon. So, apps that include your framework won't be able to get through a review process without providing a valid reason for why they need those exceptions. Apple originally planned to drop the support starting Jan 1st 2017, but they postponed it for an unknown period of time. Still, they'll do it some day. It's better to plan for the future.

P.S. If you have absolutely no control over the server, and the server developer is on Mars, and your framework really needs to communicate to that server, the app developers will probably be able to pass the review by explaining the situation ("no control over the server" is a valid reason for the Apple Review team), but each and every one of them will have to do it over and over again, and you'll have to explain in your documentation how to do it and what to say. So switching to HTTPS is easier.

Answer (score -1):

[image]Add NSAllowsArbitraryLoads as true key in your info.plist to avoid this issue.

Comment: Please don't recommend this solution without explaining that Apple will be requiring apps to provide justification for disabling ATS.